Python package is imported from src/ instead of install/ directory when using `colcon test`
I have a Python package "foo" that is build with colcon (build type "ament_python").  The package structure is like this:
foo
├── package.xml
├── pyproject.toml
├── resource
│   └── foo
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   └── foo
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ...
└── tests
    ├── test_one.py
    └── test_two.py

Since some package data is only created at build time, tests need to be run against the installed version (i.e. workspace/install/foo), not the source one, otherwise they fail due to the data missing.
However, when running tests via colcon test, foo get's imported from the source directory because somewhere in the pipeline, '.../workspace/src/foo/src' is added to sys.path.
This is not the case when I run pytest directly via python3 -m pytest tests/.
Where/why is src/ added to sys.path when using colcon test and is there a way to prevent it?

TL;DR: Explicitly specify the test directory in the pytest config.
In my case, I added
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
testpaths = "tests"

in pyproject.toml and now the tests succeed.

More context:
By turning on the debug output of colcon, I noticed that colcon test only runs python3 -m pytest in the package source directory, while manually I was running python3 -m pytest tests/.  It is not clear to me why, but this indeed made the difference.
